# Get cost of road in tce here api

Tags: here-api

I use tce routing api http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json, how can I get cost of road?  My route is draggable and I don't understand how I can get cost of the route. When I used version 6.2 I sent parameter `rollup=none,country;tollsys`, but in 7.2 that parameter doesn't work.

Thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These features are now part of the [Fleet Telematics API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/index.html). The endpoint you are looking for is https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json. This allows you to calculate a route as you would with the Routing API, but provides additional features such as toll cost calculation, driver rest times and much more.

You can find the relevant documentation for your use case [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help!